# What is the metric period for target tracking scaling policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I enabled scaling policy and I'm trying to figure out in what period I should set my threshold for. The metric I'm scaling on is `request count per target`

If I navigate to

```
Target Groups > MyTargetGroup > Monitoring > Request Count Per Target
```

The period is set to `5 Minutes` by default. I thought this would be the period in which I should set my target to, but it doesn't seem right.

What should be the correct period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen your on is a monitoring screen.  When you set the period there its only changing the graph view for that screen.

When you create the target tracking policy it will automatically create 2 CloudWatch alarms for you, a high and a low.  These alarms are what trigger the scaling policy.  Currently the values for these alarms on EC2 AutoScaling default to:
Scale out (high alarm): 3 consecutive 60 second periods
Scale in (low alarm): 15 consecutive 60 second periods

You cannot control the alarm settings other than setting the target value when using target tracking, its designed to be managed for you for ease of setup.  The target tracking settings work very well for most use cases.  If they don't want these settings you can configure your own alarms when you use step scaling instead.

Comment: Any specific reason why it is not allowed to have a lower period, let's say 10s?